# How to customize Android ChildBrowser screen and integrate it to my Phonegap app's screen

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

I am using ChildBrowser in a my Android phonegap app. And that app has a title bar. I just want to place the ChildBrowser below that title bar.

There is a js file named childbrowser.js inside the Android plugin. I used its "ChildBrowser.prototype.showWebPage" method, it calls to "showWebPage" method in ChildBrowser.Java. And then child browser is created using a dialog window and but it takes whole screen of the device. I adjusted the size of the dialog window and then I can see my app in the background but to see the app well, I should close the browser window.

How can I integrate that dialog window to my app then child browser will be displayed just below the title bar (not on the top of my app). And I am creating all screens of my app using JavaScript.

Is this possible by modifying the plugin source(like ChildBrowser.java)? If anyone can, please tell me how to modify the source to do this?

Thanks in Advance..!!